# facebook already logged in android

Tags: android, facebook

I want to check if the user is already looged in with Facebook or not,on splash screen.
I try this but its not working...

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

// Splash screen timer
AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken newAccessToken) {
            updateWithToken(newAccessToken);
        }
    };
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
    updateWithToken(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken());

}

    private void updateWithToken(AccessToken currentAccessToken) {

        if (currentAccessToken != null) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Home_Page.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    finish();
                }
            }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
        } else {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    finish();
                }
            }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your project where you are trying to log in through `Facebook`, lets say `LoginActivity`, you can user below code :

```
public static boolean isLoggedIn() {
                AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
                return accessToken != null;
 }
```

Now in your `SplashActivity`,add this code inside **onCreate()** itself.

```
    if (LoginFragment.isLoggedIn()) 
    {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
    }
```

Try this.Hope it might help.